# How to make button Swing for a big treatment

Tags: java, swing

I need to create a windows Interface using Swing to launch a java application, the probleme is that the treatment is so long so when I click the button to start it, the interface crash and I can't get any return until the treatment finish!! I don't know if I explain well the problem, I need help so anyone has an idea help me please

Comment: If you don't know why your interface crash, search about the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread), you probably new to launch this treatment in a new `Thread` ;)

Comment: Define your treatment operation and show your attempted code to help us thinking that you have minimal understanding about the problem being solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `SwingWorker` that is designed to run heavily task in another thread without blocking the gui. Here is a complete example i really like [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you make heavy task this is running in another thread not in EDT


      return null;
    }

   @Override
   protected void done() {
        //this is executed in the EDT            
   }
}
```

After the `doInBackground` method is finished the `done` method is executed. Also you might want to read about `publish(..)` and `process(..)` .

Read more [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: It surely work, but I'm not sure if the `SwingWorker` are designed to do a task like launch another java application... The `ExecutorService` may be more suitable in this case, isn't it ?

Comment: @Nizil i didn't understand the question that he has to launch another java application.. just think he want to make a very long task, you can use an executorService with a swingworker also.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because all Swing actions are processed on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

While that thread is busy doing the work to click the button it can't do anything else, such as updating the User Interface, responding to more clicks, etc.

The ways to do this are either using a `SwingWorker` or using something like an `ExecutorService` to create a new Thread to handle the processing.

Once that thread has completed (or during processing if you want to do regular updates) it can then use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to send the results back to the Swing thread to update the User Interface.

Just be aware that by doing this you allow users to do other actions while waiting - which could include clicking on the button again. You need to think about what you want the program to do in this case. One common approach is to disable the button once they have clicked it and then enable it again once the processing finishes.

You really need to read up on the Swing threading model before you get into this, as getting things wrong can break your program.

Further reading:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a long task in the EDT.

You can try this other approach:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LongTask {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame myFrame=new JFrame("Test");
      JButton myButton=new JButton("Click");
      myFrame.add(myButton);
      myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                  //Perform long task
                  //update UI using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...);
               }
            });
            t.start();
         }
      });
      myFrame.pack();
      myFrame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```